# Find Eigenvalues of a Matrix to Diagonalize

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am working on finding a matrix to diagonalize matrix $A$. Matrix $A$ is given:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -14 & 12 \\
        -20 & 17 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I was taught that finding the characteristic equation is done by finding the solution to $\det(\lambda I-A) = 0$. Doing so gave me the matrix

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda+14 & -12 \\
        20 & \lambda-17 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

This leads to $(\lambda+14)(\lambda-17) = 0$ which yields eigenvalues of $\lambda=-14$ and $\lambda=17$. However, I checked these values on [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-14%2C12%7D%2C%7B-20%2C17%7D%7D), and they give $x^2-3x+2$ as the characteristic equation and eigenvalues of $\lambda=2$ and $\lambda=1$. Can someone tell me what step I am overlooking? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Whoa! The determinant of $\lambda I-A$ isn’t $(\lambda+14)(\lambda-17)$; what should it be?

Comment: ...I really need sleep. Thank you! It should be $(\lambda+14)(\lambda-17)=-240$. It simplified to $x^2-3x+2$. Thanks for the kick in the pants!

Comment: You’re welcome! (And get some sleep. :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant of a 2x2 matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right)$ is not $ad$, but $ad-bc$. If the matrix is 3x3 the determinant has six terms, and this number grows quickly with the size of the matrix.

Comment: Long night. I realized what the mistake was. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your characteristic equation is not correct. Your mistake is on computing the determinate. Always remember trace of a matrix is equal to the summation of eigenvalues and the determinate is equal to the the multiplication.